# BadRequestError: checks.state argument is missing

Tags: node.js, express, redis, auth0

I find that every so often(not sure of the exact cadence for this error) I get the following error after the user is successfully authenticated(i.e. the url this is happening on is https://website.com/callback):

```
BadRequestError: checks.state argument is missing:
at /var/www/app/html/node_modules/express-openid-connect/middleware/auth.js:94:29 
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

I am using `express-openid-connect` v1.0.1 and the new Universal Login page. Interestingly I never run into this when testing locally, only on the server if that context helps.

**Update 1:** Another piece of the puzzle. When I get the above error and then go back to https://example.com/ and click sign in again, authentication and redirect works flawlessly without me even seeing the universal login screen.

From this point, I can logout and login to my heart's content without seeing the error again.

**Update 2:** Thought it might be something to do with cookies and the fact that the Express server runs behind Nginx and so I added:

```
app.use("trust proxy", true);
```

Still the same problem :frowning:

**Update 3:** I can now see that the first time I authenticate and get the error as described there is no cookie set on the domain. Once I go back to the landing page and attempt authentication again, the `appSession` cookie is set and persists so, from there on out(as mentioned before) sign in and sign out works as expected.

**Update 4:** I have now switched to using `express-session` and redis. Here is the config I use for `express-openid-connect`:

```
const config = {
  required: false,
  auth0Logout: true,
  appSession: false,
  handleCallback: async function (req, res, next) {
    // This will store the user identity claims in the session.
    req.session.userIdentity = req.openidTokens.claims();
    next();
  },
  getUser: async function (req) {
    return req.session.userIdentity;
  },
  baseURL:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
      ? "https://www.example.com"
      : "http://localhost:3000",
  clientID: "someid",
  issuerBaseURL: "https://site.eu.auth0.com",
};
```

I then have the following for session and redis:

```
let RedisStore = require("connect-redis")(session);
let redisClient = redis.createClient();

app.use(
  session({
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient }),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
  })
);
```

Any idea why setting the cookie the first time would fail? But then succeed on the second attempt? Is this a possible bug in the connect node module?

Has anyone else run into this problem? Any ideas on a resolution? Thank you

Comment: So, it seems like the core of this problem was caused by an HTTP call somewhere in between the HTTPS calls during the roundtrip. So, as soon as the HTTP call is made, the cookie is dropped because cookie.secure is set to true.

Setting cookie.secure to false, solved the problem. Now to figure out where the HTTP call happens. The origin site runs via HTTPS and everything is forced to be via HTTPS so, not sure if it could still happen(I guess it can), or whether this is on theAuth0 side somewhere.